# Change default alflytics logo in reports page

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer

I am using pentaho 7.1. I have to change the alflytics logo in the reports page. It takes the absolute path of the alflytics image. I want to change it to relative path. I wanted to know how and where they call the image.Please do help I am a newbie to pentaho.It actually makes a call to pentaho/getImage?image=imageadmin-6230077985905120979.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found. On changing the image in Alflytics.Reports.zip which resides in default-content and Alflytics made my work done